# Push notifications with websockets in a distributed Node.js app

Tags: node.js, nginx, websocket, push-notification

I have a Node.js application deployed on multiple servers with Nginx server load-balancing the browser traffic to these servers. The server uses push notification mechanism (using websocket module) to communicate with the browser.

In the current setup, the browser loads an application page where it opens a client socket, which connects to the server. The websocket request is sent to Nginx, which sends it to one of the servers in the cluster. When an event happens on the server, it notifies the client browsers listening to the server websocket.

The problem is that each server is communicating only with a subset of the websocket clients. Also, each server is only aware of the events that take place on the server. As a result not all clients are notified of all the server events.

I can see several potential solutions:

1. Configure Nginx to send websocket requests from each browser to all the server in the cluster. I could not figure out how to do it. Load balancing does not support broadcasting.
2. Store websocket connections in the databse, so that all servers had access to it. I am not sure how to serialize the websocket connection object to store it in MongoDB.
3. Set up a communication mechanism among the servers in the cluster (some kind message bus) and whenever event happens, have all the servers notify the websocket clients they are tracking. This somewhat complicates the system and requires the nodes to know the addresses of each other. Which package is most suitable for such a solution?

What is the simplest way to implements distributed push notification in a Node.js app?